# How to check undefined multilevel variables?

Tags: nullable, freemarker

I have this expression in Freemarker:

```
<#list data.customer.emails as email>

</#list>
```

How can I construct an `<#if>` clause to check if `data`, `data.customer` or `data.customer.emails` are undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
<#if (data.customer.emails)??>
    <#list data.customer.emails as email>
        ...
    </#list>
</#if>
```

Comment: BTW, in case you really only have a `#list` inside that `#if`, you might was well remove the `#if` and just write `<#list (data.customer.emails)![] as email>`